# File path in XML

Tags: xml

I have a .XML file and i would like to export images from it, the images are stored as file paths but i can't seem to find their origin.

Here is a example of file path i have: ":/RibbonBar/images/RibbonIcons/Home/Paste.png", I tried opening the XML in Microsoft Visual Studio but that didn't work.

I don't think i need to give any more details since my question is pretty clear.

Comment: For starters, as the drive letter is missing, have you tried searching for at least the top folder on all your partitions? Or relative to where the XML file is?